# Hex editor control for Windows Forms?

Tags: .net, winforms, controls, hex-editors

There is an old project I'd like to resurrect, and always wanted to add some hex view to it. These are my main needs:

- Easily used in .Net Windows Forms, preferable if it is written in .Net itself.
- Reliable and with a somewhat decent look and feel, nothing fancy, I just expect it to always work as expected from a hex editor, not jumping from the hex columns to its ANSI representation, and that sort of thing.
- Allows to edit values.
- Fast, although the amount of bytes loaded is gonna always be rather small.
- A license as unrestricted as possible. I'm gonna freely distribute the application and its source, which is often not a problem, however I don't want the control to impose me some unwanted license.

I've seen several open source .Net hex editors out there in my lifetime, however, since I've never really needed one, I don't recall all of them nor know which one to choose.

Comment: Neverbirth, we look for concrete answers here at SO. This is not a forum. Please try to rephrase into an actual question. It is hard to tell what is being asked here.

Comment: I think the question title says it all, and Christopher Currens replied, but will edit my message later in order to try to make it clearer. Thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've had good success with HexBox: http://sourceforge.net/projects/hexbox/